# Backquote and single quote in ruby error messages in ruby

Tags: ruby

Why does ruby uses backquote and single quote in error messages?

```
bad_method
NameError: undefined local variable or method `bad_method' for main:Object
```

As you can see method name wrapped in backquoute and single quote: `bad_method'

Why not to use two backquotes like most of ruby libraries do? Or at least to single quoutes.

Answer (score 4):

There's a chain of answers to questions like this:

#### Why do *nix-y folks single-quote like `this' instead of like 'this'?

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/75357
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/75350

#### Any reference on the usage of a backtick and single quotation mark like `this'?

- https://english.stackexchange.com/a/18669

It makes sense to me that it is copied from latex.

Comment: Both Software Engineering links are dead.