# Why do some CLIs use ` and ' rather than ‛ and ’?

Tags: character-encoding

For example, in irb

```
: > nada
NameError: undefined local variable or method `nada' for main:Object
```

Why the funky `` `nada' `` rather than just `'nada'` (or even `‛nada’`)?

I've always assumed it was to disambiguate the opening and closing marks even if working with a limited character-set, but is that actually the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wondering about this earlier today - but it happened when running ruby, not when running a REPL. Turns out it's built into [the Ruby language itself](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/606e855622c2694c6bf1a5cec59373bef0d0877e/vm_eval.c#L703).

EDIT: For the broader question of why Ruby quotes this way, I'd start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910637/backquote-and-single-quote-in-ruby-error-messages-in-ruby). Basically, you're right: it's a way of having distinct forward and backward quotes in ASCII. TeX uses those characters for that purpose.